# How to display missing dates in the data table Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

My data is all about vehicle movement. My current data is only show car that move on some particular date only. For example, if the car is not moving, the data with corresponding date is not stored. In this table, it shows that the car move on some particular date but some date are missing/not showing:

```
     Date        Count ASSET_ID       Mileage
*****************************************************
       1/7/2021            1               200
       4/7/2021            1                32
      18/7/2021            1               100
```

After the modifications, I would like to display the all date and the date that the car not moving is stored as zero. So I can count how many data for car not move in 1 month. Here the example table after the modifications that I want:

```
 Date         Count ASSET_ID          Mileage
****************************************************
    1/7/2021            1                  200
    2/7/2021            0                   0
    3/7/2021            0                   0
    4/7/2021            1                  32
    5/7/2021            0                   0
    6/7/2021            0                   0
    7/7/2021            0                   0
    8/7/2021            0                   0
    9/7/2021            0                   0
   10/7/2021            0                   0
   11/7/2021            0                   0
   12/7/2021            0                   0
   13/7/2021            0                   0
   14/7/2021            0                   0
   15/7/2021            0                   0
   16/7/2021            0                   0
   17/7/2021            0                   0
   18/7/2021            1                  100
   19/7/2021            0                   0
   20/7/2021            0                   0
   21/7/2021            0                   0
   22/7/2021            0                   0
   23/7/2021            0                   0
   24/7/2021            0                   0
   25/7/2021            0                   0
   26/7/2021            0                   0
   27/7/2021            0                   0
   28/7/2021            0                   0
   29/7/2021            0                   0
   30/7/2021            0                   0 
   31/7/2021            0                   0
```

Comment: Add a [date table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/model-date-tables) in your model.

Comment: Im not clear your question. Whats your expected outcome ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a data table would help you tremendously here.

You can use the following one (Or edit it as you please):

```
dimDate = ADDCOLUMNS (
    CALENDAR (DATE(2021,1,1),DATE(2025,12,31)),
    "DateNumber", FORMAT([Date],"YYYYMMDD"),
    "Year", YEAR([Date]),
    "MonthNo",FORMAT([Date],"MM"),
    "YearMonthNo", FORMAT([Date], "YYYY/MM"),
    "YearMonthShort", FORMAT([Date], "YYYY/mmm"),
    "MonthShort", FORMAT([Date], "mmm"),
    "Month", FORMAT([Date], "mmmm"),
    "DayNo", WEEKDAY([Date]),
    "Day", FORMAT([Date], "dddd"),
    "DayShort", FORMAT([Date], "ddd"),
    "Quarter", FORMAT([Date], "Q"),
    "YearQuarter", FORMAT([Date], "YYYY") & "/Q" & FORMAT([Date], "Q"))
```

After adding the date table and connecting it in your data model, you can use measures to calculate what days the vehicle moved / did not move.

Comment: Thank you. I can add the date table. Do you have an example on how to calculate it? appreciate your help sir.

Comment: Well, I am not entirely sure what your expected outcome would be. 
The date table helps you toward the right way, you will have to make the measures yourself. 

Perhaps using COUNTROWS(), COUNT() and filtering (By using CALCULATE() or FILTER()) will help you. If you could provide more clarity on the expected outcome (In your original post) I can edit my answer to be more complete.

Comment: I have the same problem, desired output is in the question. How to set relationship in a way that in a tabular representation left: date table, right data table, missing values of right are interpreted as 0 in order to have always eg 365 rows regardless of the days the car actually moved.